What is System.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a?
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net". Choosing "System.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.

Is it a nugget? Is it one of the imported namespace I use? Why I have "double"
Checking import namespaces and nuget suggest nothing is "double" about system.net

I have heard that some nugget contains virus. I am a bit concern.

In the proj file I saw
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Update="System.XML">
      <Name>System.XML</Name>


    <Import Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Import Include="System.Net" />
    <Import Include="System.Reflection" />



    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />


    <ImportedNamespaces>Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility=False,Newtonsoft.Json=False,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq=False,RestSharp=False,System.Collections.ObjectModel=False,System.Drawing=False,System.Net=False,system.net=False,System.Reflection=False,System.Runtime.CompilerServices=False,System.Security.Cryptography=False,System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms=False,System.Security.Cryptography.Cng=False,System.Text=False,System.Web=False,System.Windows.Forms=False,Microsoft.VisualBasic=True,System=True,System.Collections=True,System.Collections.Generic=True,System.Diagnostics=True,System.Linq=True,System.Xml.Linq=True,System.Threading.Tasks=True,nicehash3=True</ImportedNamespaces>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>8.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

So there is nothing that indicates System.net is shown twice or anything. No version 4.0.0.0

I wonder if it has something to do with
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.mshtml, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility">
      <Name>Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NiceHashBotLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\OneDrive\digitalcurrency\nicehashbot\teguh123\NiceHashBotLib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="System">
      <Name>System</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="System.Data">
      <Name>System.Data</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="System.Drawing">
      <Name>System.Drawing</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Update="System.XML">
      <Name>System.XML</Name>
    </Reference>
    <COMReference Include="Scripting">
      <Guid>{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
    </COMReference>
    <COMReference Include="SHDocVw">
      <Guid>{EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>1</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
    <COMReference Include="VBScript_RegExp_55">
      <Guid>{3F4DACA7-160D-11D2-A8E9-00104B365C9F}</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <VersionMajor>5</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>5</VersionMinor>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
    </COMReference>
    <COMReference Include="WinHttp">
      <Guid>{662901FC-6951-4854-9EB2-D9A2570F2B2E}</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <VersionMajor>5</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>1</VersionMinor>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

Like I got a bunch of .com reference that I no longer use. How to get rid of that

Hi @Andri, you can also refer to Troubleshoot assembly references. to troubleshoot this issue.

From reading this doc MSB3243, looks like that the build system sees two references of System.Net, please try the following steps:

Open your project file, in your case, it should be .vbproj file.

Search for all references to System.Net assembly.

If you find two, one to System.Net,Version=4.0.0.0 and one to System.Net, please replace the reference to System.Net with System.Net,Version=4.0.0.0.

Rebuild your project.


